# Deep diving into Rx.ReplaySubject: How to delay `next()`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, top-level-await, replaysubject

> **Ignoring Block:** Either I'm wrong here, or the whiskey is starting to work. (I don't want to rule out that I'm going stupid either. Sorry for that.)

**Expectation:**

I would have expected **ReplaySubject** to return a single value every 2 seconds because I wait two seconds (each time) before I call `next()`.

**Result:**

The result is that there is a wait of 2 seconds, but then all values are **output simultaneously**.

**The code in question is here:**

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

export const rs$: ReplaySubject<number> = new ReplaySubject();

rs$.subscribe({
  next: (data) => console.log(data),
  error: (error) => console.warn(error),
  complete: () => console.log('ReplaySubject completed'),
});

const fakeAPIValuesOne: Array<number> = [7, 11, 13];

fakeAPIValuesOne.forEach(async (entry: number) => {
  await wait(2000);  // <--- Why does wait() not work?
  rs$.next(entry);
});

function wait(milliseconds: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

**Question:**

What am I doing fundamentally wrong here?

If you want to try it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wpnqvq?file=index.ts

**EDIT 1:**

SetTimeout also has no effect. The following code does exactly the same as above:

```
fakeAPIValuesOne.forEach((value: number) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    rs$.next(value);
  }, 2000);
});
```

I wonder how `next()` can override all the delays here?

**EDIT 2**

The problem is solved, correct answer marked, thank you! You need the following details to run root level awaits for your ts-files.

**package.json**

Please notice the **type** section:

```json
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.0-dev.20220507"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

**nodemon.json**

Please consider the following config to avoid the error: `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`

```json
{
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "node --loader ts-node/esm"
  }
}
```

Last but not least **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "DOM"]
  }
}
```

Comment: one day after: was definitely not within the peak: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/ballmer_peak.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following note is extracted from mozilla web docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> **Note:** `forEach` expects a synchronous function.
>
> `forEach` does not wait for promises. Make sure you are aware of the
> implications while using promises (or async functions) as `forEach`
> callback.

So you this issue isn't related to the `ReplaySubject`, you just cannot use `forEach` for this use-case.

Cheers

**EDIT: Solved**

```
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";

export const rs$ = new ReplaySubject();

rs$.subscribe({
  next: (data) => console.log(data),
  error: (error) => console.warn(error),
  complete: () => console.log("ReplaySubject completed"),
});

const fakeAPIValuesOne = [7, 11, 13];

// That won't work:
// fakeAPIValuesOne.forEach(async (entry: number) => {
//   await wait(2000);
//   rs$.next(entry);
// });


// That will work
for (const element of fakeAPIValuesOne) {
  await wait(2000);
  rs$.next(element);
}

function wait(milliseconds: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning that you shouldn't (in general) expect this to work.

Consider the following:

```ts
wait(2000);
wait(2000);
wait(2000);
console.log("Hello");
```

"Hello" will be printed to the console right away. It's not going to wait 6 seconds.

That doesn't change if you put them in a loop.

```ts
for (const n of [1,2,3]) {
  wait(2000);
}
console.log("Hello");
```

This will also print "Hello" right away.

---

If you don't use `.then()` or `await`, the standard behavior is that you **will not** wait. Some APIs will (of course) perform an await on your behalf, but the expected behavior is that it won't.

You need to write it like this:

```ts
await wait(2000);
await wait(2000);
await wait(2000);
console.log("Hello");
```

Now you will wait 6 seconds before printing "Hello" to the console.

---

Now look at this:

```ts
const createPromise = async (v) => {
   await wait(2000);
   console.log("Hello From createPromise: ", v);
}

createPromise(1);
createPromise(2);
createPromise(3);
console.log("Hello");
```

You'll notice this isn't really any different. This will print Hello right away, and then 2 seconds later all the promises will resolve and print

```
Hello
// 2 seconds wait
Hello From createPromise: 1
Hello From createPromise: 2
Hello From createPromise: 3
```

You'll notice that none of them wait for each other. That's the expected behavior of a promise. You need to use `await` or `.then` in order to actally wait for the result of a promise.

You need to write:

```ts
await createPromise(1);
await createPromise(2);
await createPromise(3);
console.log("Hello");
```

These two loops do the same thing (as expected, they don't wait)

```ts
for (const n of [1,2,3]) {
  createPromise(n);
}

[1,2,3].forEach(n => createPromise(n))

console.log("Hello");
```

Again, the first thing you'll see printed is `"Hello"` because you never wait for any of these promises to resolve.

You do await the inner `wait(2000)` promise, but you never await the outer `createPromise()` promises. So of course you won't wait for them :)

```ts
for (const n of [1,2,3]) {
  await createPromise(n);
}
```

Comment: thank you, yes you‘re right and I admit it wasn‘t one of my greatest moments 